# Socket.io: Not able send message to particular socket using socket.id

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-redis

I am storing the socket.id of each user when he login using redis

```
redisClient.set(user._id + ':socket', socket.id)
```

When any post for this user._id is created, i am trying emit an event to the socket of that particular user using the socket.id stored above

```
var mySocket=redisClient.get(user._id + ':socket')

socket.broadcast.to(mySocket).emit('my message', msg);
```

The problem is that I am not able to emit to that particular socket using the above code.I am using socket.io version > 1.0. Can someone help me to understand if am getting the socket.id wrong way

Comment: are you sure that you are getting correct "user._id" while retrieving it from redis ?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try;

```
  io.to(socket.id).emit("event", data);
```

It Should help you..!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mahida, But I tried this and didnt work. I think the socket.id is changing and I am not storing the latest one for that user.